# matlab functions about sine curve

Tags: matlab

I have a question about matlab programming about sine curve.

The question is as below:
Consider the definition: function [s1, s2, sums] = sines(pts,amp,f1,f2). The input, pts, is an integer, but amp, f1, and f2 and are not necessarily integers. Output argument s1 is a row vector whose length (number of elements) equals pts. The elements of s1 are the values of the sine function when it is given equally spaced arguments that start at zero and extend through f1 periods of the sine. (Note that we ask for full periods, so if f1 is an integer, both the first and the last element of s1 will be 0 other than a very small rounding error.) The amplitude of the sine wave equals amp. The vector s2 is the same as s1 except that s2 contains f2 periods. The vector sums is the sum of s1 and s2. If f2 is omitted, then it should be set to a value that is 5% greater than f1. If f1 is omitted also, then it should be set to 100. If amp is not provided, then it should default to 1. Finally, if pts is omitted as well, then it should be set to 1000.

Here is what I am confused: how to define step length pts. I used the following method but it fails to work. Please help me to fix it.

```
function [s1, s2, sums] = sines(pts,amp,f1,f2)
.................
t = linspace(0, 1, pts);
s1=amp*sin(2*pi*f1*t);
s2=amp*sin(2*pi*f2*t);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Could you tell us why it fails? Personally it feels as if it should work fine. Here `pts` is the number of points that will be used rounded down to smallest integer value. Try for example `linspace(0,1,11)`. I assume that you have fixed the problems with default values or will tend to it later since it has been scaled off from the question

Comment: Also, I guess you should use double on `pts` as well as for all the other stuff as well. We are talking maximum 6 bytes of memory saving here. But you may of course mean integer value and not `int16` or `int32` or `int64`.

Comment: Maybe I made other mistakes. The auto grading program says that I made mistakes. The entire code is as follows:                              function [s1, s2, sums] = sines(pts,amp,f1,f2)
if nargin==3
    f2=1.05*f1;
end
if nargin==2
    f1=100; f2=1.05*f1;
end
if nargin==1
    amp=1; f1=100; f2=1.05*f1;
end
if nargin<1
    pts=1000;amp=1; f1=100; f2=1.05*f1;
end
t = linspace(0, 1, pts);
s1=amp*sin(2*pi*f1*t);
s2=amp*sin(2*pi*f2*t);
sum=s1+s2;
plot(sum);
end

Comment: @HaoZhang what is the error message and at what line does it appear? It would be easier to help if the full error message was provided in the question.

Comment: @HaoZhang you may also want to try out the [debugger](http://se.mathworks.com/help/matlab/debugging-code.html). It is a tool which is easy to use and really helpful. You may want to try the code after typing the line `dbstop error` in the common window. This is not the only thing the debugger can do though so I recommend you to take 5 minutes to read through the short tutorial. Good luck!

Comment: @HaoZhang you may also want to double check the `sum`. Seems you are using a variable called `sum` to calculate the sum of signals, but you return the variable `sums`. The variable name is not the same then. So you probably get a too few output arguments error or something related. Further `sums` is probable the best practice to use since `sum` is a function, but since you are not using the `sum` function it is up to you. However if this works, do not take it as a reason not to learn the debugger :). You will be sorry in the future then.

Answer (score 0):

As far as the part of the code you are confused this should work for you:

```
n=pts-1
t=0:n;
s1=amp*sin(2*pi*f1/n*t);
s2=amp*sin(2*pi*f2/n*t);
```

then you sum s1+s2. You still need to handle the missing input if any.

Comment: I doubt this is better than the already existing solution (since the submitted code is correct). Further the implementation provided by you would still give the same answer, but would force @HaoZhang to rewrite a large part of his code. Most likely to a messier variant less readable and less maintainable.

Comment: Thanks for your guideline, I have fixed this problem.